# How to create custom alias for gnuwin32 tools in Windows Powershell

Tags: command-line, powershell, alias, bash-alias

I have gnuwin32 installed and appended to my environment so I run linux/unix "ls" when I type ls in the command prompt. That's not a problem for Powershell, apparently, but I'm not being able to create a custom alias, with both the same name (ls) or a differnt name (lsa/ll/ld), and I'm getting the following error:

```
The script failed due to call depth overflow.
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (0:Int32) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CallDepthOverflow
```

Now, here's my Powershell script:

```
Set-Alias -name ls -value ListDirectory -Option AllScope

Function ListDirectory { 
    $Command = "ls -I ntuser\.* -I NTUSER\.*";
    Invoke-Expression $Command
}
```

Any ideas? About the ignore files, I need them. Just to make sure, this command works just fine in good old command prompt, I'm only having problems in Powershell :(

Comment: You are creating an infinitive loop. I'd try `$Command = "ls.exe -I ntuser\.* -I NTUSER\.*";`

Comment: Good point @LotPings, this may be the answer to my question actually!! I realized I didn't need gnuwin32 though, for now, but should I reinstall it I'll make sure to type .EXE and not just "ls" or "grep" or any other command!! Thanks hipss

Answer (score 0):

@LotPings You were correct! Adding ".exe" to **ls** did "the trick". I've added a loop to grab eventual arguments I may wanna pass to it and placed the arguments within my $Command variable. I'm not sure I did this in the best way but it works! Hehe. Thanks again!

```
# gnuwin32 "ls"
Set-Alias -name ls -value ListDirectory -Option AllScope

Function ListDirectory {
    $allArgs = "";
    For ($i=0; $i -lt $args.Length; $i++) {
        $allArgs += $args[$i] + " ";
    }

    $Command = "ls.exe $allArgs -I ntuser\.* -I NTUSER\.*";
}
```